# floated DIV's with selects creates empty columns in layout, why?

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, css-float

With the code as written below, The DIV containing SELECT 4 is pushed 2 columns to the right, but if I remove all of the SELECTS from the HTML the alignments are stacked one under the other correctly with no skipped columns. - Is there some default CSS applied to a SELECT or something I'm just missing here? Why is this occurring?

```
<div style="height:300px; text-align:right; padding-right:8px; margin-top:5px;">
<div style="float:left; width:33%;">1: <select name="brands" style="width:65%;">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
</select></div>
<div style="float:left; width:33%;">2: <input type="text" name="model" style="width:65%;" /></div>
<div style="float:left; width:33%;">3: <select name="type" style="width:65%;">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
</select>
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:33%;">4: <select name="caliber" style="width:65%;">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
</select></div>
<div style="float:left; width:33%;">6: <input type="text" name="accuracy" style="width:65%;" /></div>
<div style="float:left; width:33%;">7: <input type="text" name="finish" style="width:65%;" /></div>
<div style="float:left; width:33%;">8: <input type="text" name="action" style="width:65%;" /></div>
<div style="float:left; width:33%;">9: <input type="text" name="stock" style="width:65%;" /></div>
<div style="float:left; width:33%;">10: <input type="text" name="capacity" style="width:65%;" /></div>
<div style="float:left; width:33%;">11: <input type="text" name="chokes" style="width:65%;" /></div>
<div style="float:left; width:33%;">12: <input type="text" name="chamber" style="width:65%;" /></div>
</div>
```

[image: Layout with SELECTS]

When Selects and corresponding DIV's are removed i get this... correctly.
[image: Layout without SELECTS and DIVs]

Comment: Because that is how float is supposed to work in CSS. Have a good read of the documentation to understand why. Note that float was never intended to be used to create columns. Many people use it like that, but you have to be careful not to screw up. It's like cutting cheese with an axe.

Comment: Here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/7Z3bF/

Comment: @JoshC Thanks, adding the forced height to the style fixed the problem, but any idea why a SELECT vs a textbox has a height difference when rendered?

Comment: @Swodahs Because the `input` elements had a height of `24px`, and the `select` elements had a height of `26px`. This is a characteristic of floating elements. Therefore you just have to set the height of all elements to `26px`.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert well, a TABLE is not really appropriate either as this is not truly tabular data. Also, the DIV's are being used to control layout just as DIV's are meant to do, It doesn't seem appropriate to make them all ABSOLUTE aligned to accomplish what I believe float was better suited to perform., but thats just my opinion - thanks for the input

Comment: @JoshC thanks. Please put that as a ANSWER and I'll accept it - Since I wasn't aware that the float would change a element height that is not explicitly defined, can you advise a source that talks about the effect a float has on a elements HEIGHT?

Comment: Agreed, a table is not appropriate. What you really want is CSS3's `column-*` rules, but they don't work in old-but-still-popular versions of various browsers. I didn't say you shouldn't use float. It might be the right choice (personally I've had better luck with `display: inline-block;` for most situations). But if you're going to use `float` do not expect it to be easy or make much sense, it _is_ going to cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it isn't optimal to use inline CSS (via the `style` attribute), I rewrote everything to keep the HTML separate from the CSS. It's also worth noting that you should wrap the text for the elements in a `label` element. As you can see, you match the label's `for` attribute with an `id`.

As for the question - you simply needed to set a height on the wrapping `div` elements. The `input` elements had a height of `24px`, and the `select` elements had a height of `26px`. It is typical of floating elements to to break to a new line when the elements have differing heights. A height of `26px` would suffice. [**(working example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/7Z3bF/1/)

**CSS:**

```
form {
    height:300px;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:8px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
form > div {
    width:33%;
    float:left;
    height:26px;
}
form > div > select, form > div > input {
    width:65%;
}
```

**Updated HTML**

```
<form>
    <div>
        <label for="brands">1:</label>
        <select id="brands" name="brands">
            <option value="option1">option1</option>
            <option value="option2">option2</option>
            <option value="option3">option3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="model">2:</label>
        <input type="text" id="model" name="model" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="type">3:</label>
        <select id="type" name="type">
            <option value="option1">option1</option>
            <option value="option2">option2</option>
            <option value="option3">option3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="caliber">4:</label>
        <select id="caliber" name="caliber">
            <option value="option1">option1</option>
            <option value="option2">option2</option>
            <option value="option3">option3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="accuracy">5:</label>
        <input type="text" id="accuracy" name="accuracy" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="finish">6:</label>
        <input type="text" id="finish" name="finish" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="action">7:</label>
        <input type="text" id="action" name="action" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="stock">8:</label>
        <input type="text" id="stock" name="stock" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="capacity">9:</label>
        <input type="text" id="capacity" name="capacity" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="chokes">10:</label>
        <input type="text" id="chokes" name="chokes" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="chamber">11:</label>
        <input type="text" id="chamber" name="chamber" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Alternatively, you could avoid floating elements and use `inline-block` level elements; achieving the same effect without having to set a height on the elements.

[**Example demonstrating this**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/7Z3bF/2/)